# Regex to separate the lines of the file

Tags: java, regex

```
Lesson no 1
  lesson name: Jack and Jill went to America
  lesson contents: some XXXXX XXXXX contents
  lesson Description:  jack and jill lesson description



Lesson no 2
  lesson name: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  lesson contents: consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
  lesson Description:  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
```

I have a file like the above contents, I want to use regex to process and convert to json object using java.
Can anyone suggest regex  to process and separate the "lesson name", "lesson contents", lesson desc" etc.?

I want the output to look like this:

```
[{"Lesson no":"1","lesson name":"xxx","lesson contents":"YYY","Lesson Desc":"zzzz"},{....}]
```

Comment: Use "\R" as a regex for any line separation.

Comment: I used the the regex (?<=(Lesson no [1-9]))(\r\n)(.*) for selecting the lesson name, Here my question is how to get the lesson contents with respect to the lesson no. <br> If you want to see the result, copy the contents and paste in notepad++ and use the above said regex

Comment: Post an output of what exactly you want to get. It's not clear.

Comment: I want like json type [{"Lesson no":"1","lesson name":"xxx","lesson contents":"YYY","Lesson Desc":"zzzz"},{....}]

Answer (score 1):

To use regex you must ensure a constant structure of the file. Here I separated the lessons by 2 lines **including after the final lesson**. You can programatically append those lines after reading the file, or use just 1 empty line between them etc.

```
Lesson no 1
lesson name: Jack and Jill went to America
lesson contents: some XXXXX XXXXX contents with new
lines
lesson Description: jack and Jill lesson description with new
lines


Lesson no 2
lesson name: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
lesson contents: consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
lesson Description:  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
<this is an empty line>
<this is an empty line>
```

The code matches the structure of a single lesson repeatedly and breaks it into components. If your input file changes then you need to change the `pattern` variable accordingly.

Note: On Java 8 you don't need the `lb` string at all, replace it with "\\R".

```
public class Regex {

    static String lb = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    static String path = "src/test/text.txt";
    static String pattern = "(Lesson no) (.+?)"+lb+"(lesson name): (.+?)"+lb+"(lesson contents): (.+?)"+lb+"(lesson Description): (.+?)"+lb+lb;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = null;
        try {
            text = new Scanner(new File(path)).useDelimiter("\\z").next();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher m = pat.matcher(text);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");
        while (m.find()) {
            sb.append("{");
            for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
                sb.append("\"").append(m.group(i));
                if (i%2 == 0)
                    sb.append("\",");
                else
                    sb.append("\":");
            }
            sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1).append("},");
        }
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1).append("]");
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

The output is

```
[{"Lesson no":"1","lesson name":"Jack and Jill went to America","lesson contents":"some XXXXX XXXXX contents with new
lines","lesson Description":"jack and Jill lesson description with new
lines"},{"Lesson no":"2","lesson name":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet","lesson contents":"consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor","lesson Description":" Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor"}]
```

Comment: Thanks man. but you are changing the structure of the file... Can you please tell the regex matching multiple lines "starting from specified word and ending with specified word"

Comment: What's the *exact* original structure?

Comment: Lesson no.1<br/>This lesson is part math, part magic and all art.<br/>Students fold a piece of paper in half, draw on one side and press to create a symmetrical butterfly. If you have time, it’s wonderful to cut out the butterfly and add glue lines along parts of the butterfly and then sprinkle with glitter. I have done this in the past but strangely enough, I have no photographic records! - See more at: <br/> Translation: The brief description of the lesson.<br/> <br/><br/> The line numbers may vary for each lesson.

Comment: This is totally different from what you originally posted. Please edit your question to include the *exact* structure (content is not important) of of the input and the *exact* form of the output.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by searching for the lesson name.  More specifically, we want to find the stuff that is immediately after "lesson name:", but before the newline.  Here is a regex:

```
lesson name:\s*(.*)
```

As you can see, it searches for "lesson name:".  Then **\s** matches any whitespace character, and the star means 0 or more times.  This is nice because if you accidentally had no spaces or maybe 2 spaces immediately after "lesson name:", it would still catch it.

Finally, the dot matches ANY character EXCEPT NEWLINE.  The star means 0 or more times, so we match the rest of the line.  Because that part is in parenthesis, it is stored in a variable in Java.

I am not too familiar with Java, but i think you have to get the match like this (if anyone sees an error pls let me know)....

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile('lesson name:\s*(.*)');
Matcher m = regex.matcher(yourfilestring);
if(m.find()){
  System.out.println(m.group(1)); // 1 is for the first set of parenthesis in the regex
}
```

You can apply this concept to get things following "Lesson no", "lesson contents:", and "lesson Description:" too.

Comment: Ok! I can search lesson name like this ... what about lesson description, It contains multiple line and also new lines how to search the description (just answer this question), I may get the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
            while (scanner.hasNext()){
                String string = scanner.useDelimiter("\n").next();
                if(string.contains("Lesson no")){
                    System.out.print(string );
                }
                else{
                    if(!string.equals(" ") && !string.equals("\n") && !string.equals("") && !string.equals("\r")){
                        if(string.contains(":")){
                            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(string,":");
                            String key ="";
                            String value = "";

                            while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
                                key = st.nextElement().toString();
                                value = st.nextElement().toString();

                                System.out.print(" " +key +" : "+ value); 
                            }
                        }

                        else{
                            System.out.println(string);
                        }

                    }//if(!string.equals(" "))
                }


            }//while
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I hope that can help